# How to generate an animation with images in subplots (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, subplot

Is possible to animate pairs of images in a jupyter notebook?

With two lists of images:

```
greys = io.imread_collection(path_greys)
grdTru= io.imread_collection(path_grdTru)
```

The following naïve code fails to generate an animation:

```
for idx in range(1,900):
    plt.subplot(121)
    plt.imshow(greys[idx], interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    plt.subplot(122)
    plt.imshow(grdTru[idx], interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.,vmin=0,vmax=3)
    plt.show()
```

(It generates a list of subplots)

By the way,the [example found in matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html) doc failed if pasted in a notebook.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make [the example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html) work in a jupyter notebook you need to include the

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

magic command.

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()


def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)

im = plt.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True)


def updatefig(*args):
    global x, y
    x += np.pi / 15.
    y += np.pi / 20.
    im.set_array(f(x, y))
    return im,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=50, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

You can then easily adapt it to your list of images.

From matplotlib version 2.1 on you also have the option to create a JavaScript animation inline.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)

im = plt.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True);


def updatefig(*args):
    global x, y
    x += np.pi / 15.
    y += np.pi / 20.
    im.set_array(f(x, y))
    return im,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=50, blit=True)

from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to do this with multiple subplots.